# Are surjective functions really functions?

Tags: functions

A function maps element $x\in X$ to UNIQUE element $f(x) \in Y$. Surjection does not imply uniqueness. Are surjective functions functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surjection implies for every $y \in Y$ there is $x \in X$ such that $ x \mapsto y$. The definitions of function and surjective functions are completely different, and it's meaningless to talk about a "surjective function" without a precondition that the object is a function. We can, however, have surjective relations that aren't functions. For example, if $X=\{0\}$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$, the relation defined by $\{(0,0), (0,1)\}$ is surjective.

Comment: So $x$ need not to be unique. It is only uniqueness from $x$ to $y$ but not the other way around?

Comment: @FemaleTank when $x$ is unique we have an bijection.

Comment: you are better at math than euler!

Comment: @FemaleTank that's a good joke

Answer (score 4):

You seem to confusing the properties of "well-definedness" and "injectivity".  For a mapping to be a function, it need merely map each element in the domain to a single element in the codomain (this is well-definedness).  However, this does not preclude more than one element in the DOMAIN from mapping to the same element of the codomain.  Do you see how that is?  A surjective function takes advantage of this possibility.  An INJECTIVE function is a function where each element of the domain maps to a DIFFERENT/UNIQUE element of the codomain.

Comment: Oh......Okay so x need not to be unique I git it!

Answer (score 1):

I think if we're talking about a surjection then we're assuming it's a function to begin with